# how do i remove path and names from pages in magento

Tags: magento-1.9, page-title

[image]

I need to remove this from all of the pages.

Answer (score 1):

Those are breadcrumbs. You can completely remove them from all pages by adding the following line into your own layout.xml file.

`<remove name="breadcrumbs.container"/>`

You can define your own layout.xml file for your module by adding something like the following into your magento modules `config.xml`

```
<frontend>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <namespace_module modules="Namespace_Module">
                <file>namespace_module.xml</file>
            </namespace_module>
        </updates>
    </layout>
</frontend>
```

Then the `layout.xml` file would look something like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layout>
    <default>
        <remove name="breadcrumbs.container"/>
    </default>
</layout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add This tag in local.xml file of your theme

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
    <layout version="0.1.0">
        <default>     
            <remove name="breadcrumbs"/>
        </default>
    </layout>
```

Comment: i am not able to find the path, there are too many files with same name.

Comment: can you please tell me where i will find local.xml, its not present in /public_html/app/design/frontend/apptha/mageshop/layout

Comment: you can add this tag inside app/design/frontend/packagename/themename/layout/local.xml
if local.xml is not exist , you need to add new file.

Comment: If you not know your theme name and package name, so go to admin ->System ->Select Configuration -> Click on Design where you can find your theme and package name folder name